# Subfolder traversing us os.walk in python

Tags: python, operating-system, os.walk

I am trying to make a python code that traverse all subfolders in a parent folder and moves the subfolder contents to the parent folder.I used **os.walk** function in python but it keeps selecting the files in the parent folder as well.Is there a way to solve this..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us your code so that we can debug your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
for current_folder,subfolders_in_cwd,files_in_cwd in os.walk(some_dir_path):
    print "Folders in %s = %s"%(current_folder,subfolders_in_cwd)
```

Comment: It seems that this piece of code  works only for the first level of subfolders..i was looking  to traverse till the base level of all subfolders ...Is it possible using recursion  ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
PATH = '/home/pi/Public/'
for root, folder, files in os.walk(PATH):
    files.sort(key=str.lower) #Sorts files alphabetically
    subFolder.sort()
    for item in files:
        fileNamePath = os.path.join(root, item)
        print(fileNamePath)
```